Why Does marker-pdf Split Images into Two, and How Can I Fix It?
I’m working on a project where I want to convert pdf files to markdown, and I’m using the marker-pdf library for this. However, I’m encountering an issue where the extracted images are being split into two parts.
Here is what I have tried:
pip install marker-pdf

(you can also check: https://pypi.org/project/marker-pdf/)
marker_single /path/to/file.pdf /path/to/output/folder --batch_multiplier 2 --max_pages 10 
And then it generated a md file with the images that were in that pdf file:
generated folder
This pdf file contains images like this: pdf file
but the generated md file looks like this: Markdown file
The images extracted are sometimes split into two parts. I suspect it might be related to the bounding box calculation or how the marker-pdf library handles image blocks and regions.
Any insights or solutions to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated!

maybe submit a bug report to the marker lib with a small PDF where that happens?

@KJ So how do you suggest solving the problem?

@KJ please check it again, that is all the information I can give you.

I agree it looks like a bounding box calculation problem (contour extraction problem). I have gotten very good results at identifying images within a PDF with OpenCV by only using the extreme outer flags for contour extraction. I don't know if there is a way you can configure it to do that. I also wonder if configuring it that way would affect the OCR.

@KJ I don't think that is how surya does it though (which is what Marker uses). I think it just rasterizes each page of the pdf and applies the same processing on the result that it does when analyzing images.
